# How to implement C# Reflection code in Python?

Tags: python, c#, reflection

I am working on a test automation project that requires the use of reflection with a keyword driven framework. I am having trouble finding Python equivalents for C# methods.

```
Type t = Type.GetType(FullPathForReflection + Page);
PropertyInfo getPropInfo = t.GetProperty(Object);
var createdClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t, AppiumSession);
WindowsElement getObjectProp = (WindowsElement) getPropInfo.GetValue(createdClassInstance);
keywordClass.processKeywords(Keyword, getObjectProp, Value);
```

I'm using `type()` to replace `Type.GetType()` but can't find any equivalents for `GetProperty(object)` or `GetValue()`. Also, I am using `t()` as a replacement for `Activator.CreateInstance` and that seems to work.

If anyone could help me find replacement methods or equivalents that would be amazing! Thank you!

Comment: This isn't exactly the same but: If "T" is a class then "T.__dict__" is a dictionary with the methods and class-bound attributes of "T" (plus some other things). To retrieve an attribute value from an object "instance" where the attribute name is a string in variable "name" there is "getattr(instance, name)".